# Test whether a property name exists

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting this error:

> Run-time error '424' object required

when I try to run this code:

```
Sub SuperSaveAs()
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim pathName As String
Dim myFileName As String

If (ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("_CheckOutSrcUrl").Value = True) Then
    pathName = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("_CheckOutSrcUrl").Value
    myFileName = pathName + ActiveWorkbook.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            myFileName _
            , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Else
    MsgBox "_CheckOutSrcUrl is missing"
End If

End Sub
```

This macro is connected with a button in Excel. The macro checks if the custom document property exists. If the custom document property exists the macro should save the file to the Value of `_CheckOutSrcUrl` (SharePoint Directory).
How can I fix the error?

Comment: Excel doesn't have an `ActiveDocument` - it's `ActiveWorkbook`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot use the above method to test whether a property name exists or not.  There are two apparent approaches, and these are not my own personal answers:

1. Use a loop to examine all the property names and see if "_CheckOutSrcUrl" gets found.  See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/using-customdocumentproperties-with-vba/91ef15eb-b089-4c9b-a8a7-1685d073fb9f
2. Use VBA error detection to see if the property "_CheckOutSrcUrl" exists.  See http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?15366-Solved-CustomDocumentProperties-Problem

A snippet example of #1 adapted to your code - would be best in a function:

```
Dim propertyExists As Boolean
Dim prop As DocumentProperty
propertyExists = False
For Each prop In ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
    If prop.Name = "_CheckOutSrcUrl" Then
        propertyExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next prop
```

A snippet example of #2 adapted to your code:

```
Dim propertyExists As Boolean
Dim tempObj
On Error Resume Next
Set tempObj = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("_CheckOutSrcUrl")
propertyExists = (Err = 0)
On Error Goto 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Cybermike:

```
Function propertyExists(propName) As Boolean

    Dim tempObj
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tempObj = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(propName)
    propertyExists = (Err = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```