# Check existence of a given ItemProperty for a generic Object

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a `Sub` that takes as argument a generic Object `olObj`. I want access a given property of the object, only if it exists.

I wrote the `Function` below to check for this.
I conceive also using error handling for this.
**Is there any other way?** (e.g., something like `HasItemProperty` which does not need to sweep through all `ItemProperties` and check one by one).

```
    Function HasItemProperty(ByRef olObj As Object, ByVal ipname As String) As Boolean
        HasItemProperty = False
        Dim ips As ItemProperties
        Set ips = olObj.ItemProperties
        Dim iip As Integer
        For iip = 0 To ips.Count - 1
          Dim ip As ItemProperty
          Set ip = ips.Item(iip)
          Dim ipn As String
          ipn = ip.Name
          If (ipn = ipname) Then
            HasItemProperty = True
            Exit Function
          End If
        Next iip
    End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test whether a property name exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204801/test-whether-a-property-name-exists)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - I think it is far from being a dupe. The other question (surprisingly, asked yesterday also!) refers to Excel VBA, this one refers to Outlook VBA. The methods are different (`CustomDocumentProperties` vs. `ItemProperties`, e.g.), which is enough for not being a dupe. Anyone finding the other answer would not be able to use it for Outlook. Moreover, I am asking a different question (see boldface). PS: The ideas involved in the two methods proposed in the accepted answer there are the same as those proposed in my OP here.

Comment: It's the exact same idea. Cycle through all properties to see if that particular property name is there; or just try it our and catch the error if it fails. Those are the two possibilities, both are illustrated in that answer, and both can be adapted to Outlook with minor changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially you want to check if your object exposes a particular property, like `olObj.SomeProperty`?

Not in VBA. On the low level (C++, Delphi, etc.), you can call `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames`. But why not simply access the property (`olObj.SomeProperty`) and handle the exception (`on Error Resume Next`, `Err.Number` / `Err.Clear`)?

Comment: *So essentially you want to...?*: Yes, that is what I wanted (preferably but not stated, using the property name as an argument of a `Sub`). Your proposal with VBA is also included in my OP, although I did not post code for that either. *... why not simply...?*: I wanted to know about alternatives. Regarding your proposal with `GetIDsOfNames` (beyond the scope, but a nice addition), would that avoid iterating across properties to check?

Comment: Yes, it would, but IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames  / Invoke are not directly accessible in VB script. JavaScript can do that using SomeObject['PropertyName'] syntax, but it does not work in VB script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's a bit inelegant that's for sure. If the property fetch fails then it sets the flag to false and goes about it's merry way.

You can toggle the comment for `testProperty`

```
Sub marine()
Dim testObj As Object
Dim propertyValid As Boolean
Dim testProperty As String


On Error GoTo PROPERR
Set testObj = Sheets(1)
testProperty = testObj.Name
'testProperty = testObj.ThisDoesNotExist

propertyValid = True
PROPRETURN:
Exit Sub


PROPERR:
propertyValid = False
GoTo PROPRETURN
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a snippet for my proposed Error handling method. This one appears to be suitable for Excel, although easily adapted for Outlook. A more elegant form can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29205176/2707864).

Comment: @sancho.s I would argue neither solution is actually elegant. Functional no doubt but the root of the solution, test for failure and handle accordingly, irks me.

Answer (score -2):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any other way. You need to iterate over all properties in the collection to find the one you need.